# Visual Studio error building a solution with WPF application

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

When I am trying to build a solution file which has WPF projects, I get this error

> Could not copy the file "bin\Debug\test.exe.config" because it was not
>   found.

I tried Clean Solution, Rebuild solution. Tried deleting the bin directory. This started yesterday. Not sure what I changed.

How do I fix this. so I can do a build.

Comment: did you have the `App.config` in your solution explorer?

Comment: yes. And it was set up for all the environments too

Comment: Why would it try to copy the config file FROM `bin\debug\`. that doesn't make sense. check for post-build-events in your project's properties

Comment: Yes. I doesn't make sense to me too. I was confused too. So I posted here to see if anybody had similar issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. The problem with my solution was a extension(a config Transform extension) that was installed. I updated the Visual studio extension and the build succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but anti-virus software could potentially cause this type of problem if it decides that your exe is suspicious.

If you have any AV software running, try disabling it temporarily, and/or excluding your project build folders from its protection.